# When is the projective line the seminaive projective line?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Excuse the possible naivete of this question.  Since reading a nice survey article by Daniel Biss a few years ago, I'm always worried about what $P^1(R)$ is, for a ring $R$.

So that I stop worrying, I'm looking for an answer to the following question:  For what (commutative, of course) rings $R$ is it true that $P^1(R)$ is naturally identifiable with the set of pairs $(a,b) \in R^2$ such that $(a,b)$ equals the unit ideal, modulo the natural action of $R^\times$?

Comment: Similar discussion: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/46116/a-valued-points-of-projective-space

Comment: Thanks - I couldn't find that discussion when I searched earlier.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is equivalent to the property that every invertible (=rank-1 projective) $R$-module generated by two elements is free. Examples: semilocal rings, unique factorization domains, finite products of such rings.

Comment: And in the Dedekind case, trivial class group is also necessary. 

Comment: I think even for one-dimensional Noetherian domains, this property forces the Picard group to be trivial.